# Find unitary $U$ that transforms state $|\phi \rangle$ to state $|\phi' \rangle$ knowing those states differ only by relative phase

Tags: quantum-gate, quantum-state, unitarity

Given:

$|\phi \rangle = \sum_n c_n |a_n \rangle $

$|\phi' \rangle = \sum_n c'_n |a_n \rangle $

such that $\forall n: c_n = c'_n \lor c_n = -c'_n $, where $|a_n \rangle $ is a canonical basis,

and assuming that I can generate states $|\phi \rangle$  and  $|\phi' \rangle$ arbitrary many times, how can I find $U$ such that $U$ $|\phi \rangle = |\phi' \rangle$?

I know that $U$ has to be equal to some tensor product of $I$ and Pauli-$Z$ gates. So the naive solution would be to generate all of the $2^n$ unitaries, apply each of them to $|\phi \rangle$, and calculate the trace distance between the obtained state and $|\phi' \rangle$ to find the $U$ gate. However, I'm wondering if it's possible to find the $U$ gate in sub-exponential time?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking for: If all you need is to change the relative phases, the $U$ is simply a diagonal matrix with $\pm 1$ depending on which coefficients are flipped in sign. Any such matrix, as you said, can be obtained by composing $\sigma_z$ or tensor products of them.

Comment: Yes, but I don't know which coefficients have to be +1 and which -1, all I know is that there must exist such a matrix. There are in total $2^n$ such diagonal matrices and I want to find out if there is a faster way than simply trying all of them.

Comment: First, there are $2^{n-1}$ unitaries since the global phases don't matter and two unitaries that are exact sign flips of each other are identical (i.e., only half of $2^n$ unitaries are needed). Second, can you clarify the setting? I.e., are you looking for a quantum protocol that finds such a $U$ or are you looking to find this numerically on a classical computer?

Comment: I'm looking for a quantum protocol (i.e. I don't have access to $|\phi \rangle$ and $|\phi' \rangle$ state vectors). Let's say I have two quantum circuits, one to generate $|\phi \rangle$ and one to generate $|\phi' \rangle$. I want to modify one of them so that they both generate the same state.